# ifup eth0: unknown host

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, recovery-mode, ifconfig

unfortunately, i am in Ubuntu Recovery Mode.
I need Internet connection but, i fail to bring it up.

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s2  Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr xxxx
        inet addr:
        inet6 addr:
       ...
lo      Link encap:local
       ...

$ sudo ifup enp0s2
Ignoring unknown interface enp0s2=enp0s2

$ sudo ifconfig up enp0s2
enp0s2: Unknown host
```

The router has connection to the Internet and the laptop is proper connected via cable.

So, why nobody loves me?
And, how do i bring Ethernet up?

BTW: why is it 'enp0s2' and not 'eth0' as usual?

Comment: did you remount your root partition rw ? see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remount root read-write:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

This is so you can edit files under `/etc/`.

Edit `/etc/network/interfaces`

Add:

```
auto enp0s2
iface enp0s2 inet dhcp
```

Run: `ifup enp0s2`

It is 'enp0s2' and not 'eth0' because of kernel modifications that were added to support [Predictable Network Interface Names](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)

Comment: Nice. 'ifup' works now. But, still i can't 'ping google.com'. It says 'unknown host'.

Comment: Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` add `nameserver 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Nope. ping still aint working. Although, i didnt restart anything.

Comment: Does `ping -n 8.8.4.4` work?

Comment: $ ping -n 8.8.4.4
connect: Network is unreachable

Comment: Sorry, my bad. A typo in /etc/network/interfaces. Works now. (Although, one question from the initial post still unanswered...)

Comment: Nobody loves you because you don't understand what love is. If you understood what love is you would realize how much you are loved.

Comment: @MettaCrawler, will this solution work, if I want to `enable` eth0? And what is the reason of remounting root?