# Ping returns Unknown Host and no eth0

Tags: ethernet, ping

Per this AskUbuntu post ([ifup eth0: unknown host](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741595/ifup-eth0-unknown-host#)) the OP couldn't ping google.com His answer was to modify `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto enp0s2
iface enp0s2 inet dhcp
```

After re-installation of 16.04, Ubuntu called the Ethernet port `enp6s0`. So would I edit `/etc/network/interfaces` to show the above, or change `enp0s2` to `enp6s0`?

Comment: If you want it to apply to your hardware, you will have to replace `enp0s2` with `enp6s0`. Also, read the help, and learn to format your posts. **BEWARE** You used `/interfaces` to refer to the file. This is wrong. It's `/etc/network/interfaces`. `/interfaces` is a different (nonexistent and/or not used by networking) file entirely.

Comment: ... also note that if you're using Ubuntu 16.04 *Desktop*, then external interfaces are handled by `NetworkManager` rather than being defined in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file (at least by default)

Comment: This is a Desktop 'puter, not a server. Please point me to the template or similar in NetworkManager to change eth0 to enp6s0.

Comment: Network Manager will do so automatically. There is nothing to change there.